# How to access localhost with a port on a Virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, localhost

I installed a Virtual PC with Windows7 and opened connection to my machine's localhost.

My computer's name is memphis, I added the following line in hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 memphis
```

and I also updated **IIS** default website bindings to include:

```
memphis, 80, All unassigned
```

Now, in the virtual machine IE9 I typed:

```
http://memphis/
```

This worked well, and displayed directory content... Then I added a new website under IIS, and changed it's bindings to

```
localhost 900, and memphis 900
```

On my machine that works well, but in Vritual PC IE I typed:

```
http://memphis:900/
```

And I get Page cannot be displayed... what is going on? Why couldn't I access a different port on the Virtual PC?

Comment: So you're trying to access an HTTPD that is running on the host, from your guest?

Comment: Might not be relevant but in your example you use a comma before the port number: "memphis, 80, All unassigned", but in the new website bindings you have "localhost 900, and memphis 900".

Comment: @leathe no they are the same, I use the console in IIS to add new binding that's all

Comment: @OliverSalzburg well if I understood your question, I am trying to run a site on my local machine IIS (the host) on the Virtual PC (the guest)

Comment: Does the host/guest allow port 900 through at all?

Comment: @Leathe how do I know that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install a Virtual PC instance, it's like a completely new computer, `localhost` will refer to two different machines depending on if you're resolving it on the host (your physical computer) or the guest (the Virtual PC instance).

You don't have to put anything into your `hosts` file to make your computer name known to the host. The host knows its own name.

You can put the name of your host into the `hosts` file on the guest, but as long as they're sharing the same network, this shouldn't be required (due to Windows' peer-to-peer name resolution), but it shouldn't hurt either.

The port used by your HTTPD (IIS) will always be 80. You just have to access your host through it's network IP address (like `192.168.1.10`, *not* `127.0.0.1`).

In case you want to use a non-standard HTTP port (like 900), it is possible that you have to manually open that port in the Windows Firewall for your guest to be able to connect to it.

The process is outlined in [this answers](https://superuser.com/a/92494/36744), but here it is adjusted for your case:

> 1. Go to the Control Panel and launch **Windows Firewall**.
> 2. Go to **Advanced Settings**
> 3. Select **Inbound Rules** in the left pane
> 4. Select **New Rule** in the right pane
> 5. In the New Inbound Rule Wizard, select **Port** as Rule Type, then click on **Next**
> 6. Select **TCP** and put **900** (and any other ports you want to open) in **Specific 
>      local ports**, then click on **Next**
> 7. Select **Allow the connection**, then click on **Next**
> 8. Select the network location where the rule should apply (select them all if you're not sure), then click on **Next**
> 9. Give a name and an optional description

Comment: well, my Windows7 Ultimate always had issues with these protocols, I think its a proxy setting that I cannot figure out... basically, 192.168.*.* did not work without first adding it to bindings of IIS, I tried removing memphis from hosts, my machine stops recognizing http://memphis/ (yes i know, odd but I never was able to solve this problem). Anyways, my problem wasn't in default 80, it was in 900 port, maybe I should try a different port number?

Comment: @Ayyash: Well, true, you would have to add the `192.168.x.x` address to your IIS bindings, otherwise you won't be able to use it, I guess. So, if I understand you correctly now, everything is working as intended on port 80, but only port 900 isn't? In that case, did you make sure to open that port in the Windows firewall?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @Ayyash: Check this answer: http://superuser.com/a/92494/36744

Comment: @Ayyash: Great! :) I'll update my answer to reflect this.